# What happens when I delete the Task related to an EmailMessage?

Tags: email, tasks, relationships, activities, emailmessage

We're looking for ways to get rid of some data in several orgs. One potential target would be the Task records that get created along with every EmailMessage. (I.e. the Tasks of which the Id is stored in the ActivityId field on the EmailMessage records)

What would happen when we delete those Task records? For the few that I tried, I did not seem to see any difference in Salesforce. Do these Task records actually serve a purpose?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Note:* Some of the following is conclusions my team reached for which we could not find explicit documentation; Salesforce support eventually confirmed our findings, just this past week.

The `EmailMessage` object does not have any explicit CRUD or Sharing Settings.  There is also no `EmailMessage__Share` object, so Apex sharing is off the table.  With no explicit CRUD, you cannot assign "View All" at the object level.

With no explicit sharing options, Salesforce defaults to 'Controlled by Parent'.  `EmailMessage` has a `ParentId` field, which is a lookup to `Case` (I believe because the `EmailMessage` object was originally added to support Email-to-Case).  If this field is present the case is the parent and sharing is controlled by the case.  Otherwise, `ActivityId` is used, and the auto-generated `Task` becomes the parent.  Task sharing is a bit complicated as it can use `WhoId` or `WhatId`, and a `Contact` as the `WhoId` would then depend on the contact's `Account` lookup.

The result is that even if you build a custom Activity Feed to replace the Activity related list, only the `EmailMessage`'s owner would be able to see it without the `Task`.  We had originally added a trigger on `EmailMessage` to remove these tasks, which we eventually removed for this reason.

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth: I found that the Task record is necessary to have the EmailMessage appear in the Activity Related list on the Contact record and other Related records. So if we delete the Task record, the EmailMessage will disappear from the Contact's Activity history.

Only exception: the email will still remain visible in the Case Feed, so there's a special mechanism built in there, probably based on the ParentId of the EmailMessage.